# MAX SQL Query clarifications

Tags: sql-server

I have below Tables

```
Table1          
DATE      |TASK |APPROVAL|PROD_ID
1/02/2018 | 1   |xyz     |MT

TABLE2          
DATE     |TASK  |APRROVAL|PROD
1/02/2018|  2   |xyz     |SS
1/02/2018|  3   |xyz     |TT
1/02/2018|  4   |xyz     |MT
```

I need to get only one maximum task, but below is my query returns all the result

```
select max(table2.task),table1.date,table1.prod_id from table1
join table2 on table1.approval=table2.aprroval
group by table1.date,table1.prod_id
```

But i am getting all the records

Comment: check this -. select max(table2.task),table1.date,table1.prod_id from table1
join table2 on table1.approval=table2.aprroval and table1.PROD_ID = table2.PROD
group by table1.date,table1.prod_id

Comment: Thanks for this, however some times the table2 approval coloumns is blank.

Comment: Use this select max(table2.task),table1.date,table1.prod_id from table1 join table2 on table1.approval=table2.aprroval and ( table1.PROD_ID = table2.PROD or  table2.PROD is NULL ) group by table1.date,table1.prod_id

Comment: sorry, still i am getting 4 records

Comment: can you share few records from both the tables with DDL. and the output you need.

Comment: I have two tables - Table - a with task and look up with table b (has mulitple rows for single approval ). For ex i want to get the highest task for the approval  from table b .Your query seems to be correct logicall but still i am getting all three record from the table b.any idea.

Comment: table1.PROD_ID = table2.PROD or table2.PROD is NULL this condition returns multiple record as i have two records for the same approval one with email and other with null.Since we put or condition it takes two recordselect 
ms.task,
ms.date
from table1
join 
(select max(table2.task),table2.email 
group by table2.email) ---> this returns multiple record instead of highest when i group by email as email is required)
latest
table1.task=latest.task

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting

```
select top (1) table2.task, table1.date,table1.prod_id from
 table1 join table2 on table1.approval=table2.aprroval
 Order by table2.task
```

EDIT;

I re-read your question properly, try this;

```
select top(1) from 
(
   select * from table1
union all
   select * from table2
) as t
order by t.date
```

Comment: Thanks, i am using this select to insert into another table, and table2.task is the 3rd colum

Comment: insert      *  into wf_flow          select  table1.date,table1.prod_id, top 1 table2.task from
 table1 join table2 on table1.approval=table2.aprroval
 group by table1.date,table1.prod_id    error getting Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'.

Comment: Forgot brackets - it should be top(n)

Comment: With luck removing the group by and changing it to order by fixed it. And gets the desired output

Comment: it doesnt help, however i have modified my query like this select 
ms.task,
ms.date
from table1
join 
(select max(table2.task),table2.email 
group by table2.email) ---> this returns multiple record instead of highest when i group by email as email is required)
latest
table1.task=latest.task
 still i getting all the records instead of latest